# Как спарсить ссылку на продавца?

Tags: python, парсер, beautiful-soup

Есть сайт kufar.by, с любого товара оттуда я пытаюсь спарсить ссылку на продавца следующим кодом:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

src = requests.get("https://www.kufar.by/item/137097961").text

soup = BeautifulSoup(src, "lxml")
item = soup.find("a", class_="kf-Fqrg-c7f38")
print(item)
```

Выводит результат `None`, в чём может быть ошибка?

Comment: Так там всё на скриптах генерится. Используйте `Selenium`

Comment: CrazyElz, спасибо!